# Google Script onedit(e) event restricted to a specific sheet and specific range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have scoured and found mostly what I am looking for. I have made a few modifications to what I found and it works... Mostly. BUT when I make an edit in a different sheet in column C it runs the onedit() in the DATA sheet. I do not want that and I can not get it to stop.

I only want it to monitor 'Data' sheet. for ranges C3:C5000 or C3:C+lastrow which would be ideal. There should be no more than 5000 rows.

```
function onEdit(e) {  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data_sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var editRange = ss.getActiveRange();
  var editRow = editRange.getRow();
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
  var range = data_sheet.getRange("C3:C5000");
  var rangeRowStart = range.getRow();
  var rangeRowEnd = rangeRowStart + range.getHeight();
  var rangeColStart = range.getColumn();
  var rangeColEnd = rangeColStart + range.getWidth();
  if (editRow >= rangeRowStart && editRow <= rangeRowEnd 
      && editCol >= rangeColStart && editCol <= rangeColEnd)
  {
    RefreshImport2();
   }
}
```

Comment: I have also seen it repeat itself in a loop. Because the RefreshImport function senses the edited blank C5 then populates it with a formula, waits a split second then copies it to a variable and pastes values only. 

Can the onedit function be triggered by the editing caused by a script editing in column C? If so can we avoid that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can retrieve several information for editing by using the event object `e` of `onEdit(e)`. The detail information for the event object is [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events). So how about this sample script? In this sample,

When you edit cell on Spreadsheet, if the sheet name, column and row are `Data`, `C` and `3 <= row <= 5000`, respectively, `RefreshImport2()` is run.

#### Sample script :

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (
    e.source.getSheetName() == "Data" &&
    e.range.columnStart == 3 &&
    e.range.columnEnd == 3 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 3 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 5000
  ) {
    RefreshImport2();
  }
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

#### Edit :

You can do it by adding one more if statement. At 1st if statement, it is used when the sheet name is `Data`. At 2nd if statement, it is used when the sheet name is `Data Entry`. Each if statement is not interfered with each other.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if (
    e.source.getSheetName() == "Data" &&
    e.range.columnStart == 3 &&
    e.range.columnEnd == 3 &&
    e.range.rowStart >= 3 &&
    e.range.rowEnd <= 5000
  ) {
    RefreshImport2();
  }

  if (e.source.getSheetName() == "Data Entry") {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: That did the job. Looks much more simple too.

So can I then can I copy the If statement, change sheetname to 'Data Entry' and have 2 if statements in onedit(e) ? So if there is an edit in data entry section, it will repopulate the formulas?

Comment: @Arlen Gregory I updated my answer. Please confirm it.