# How to make the onEdit() event object e work when copying and pasting values into blank cells or non-blank cells in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Following my last post here[How to delete a cell's value previously set by the event object (e) of the simple trigger onEdit() in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56444249/how-to-delete-a-cells-value-previously-set-by-the-event-object-e-of-the-simpl) 
I found that it doesn't print into A2 when pasting into a blank cell B2.

Here's the code again:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg = e.range,
    row = rg.rowStart,
    col = rg.columnStart,
    sht = rg.getSheet();

  //exit code
  if (col !== 2 || sht.getName() !== 'Sheet1' || row === 1) return;

  // When the empty cell is edited, this becomes true.
  if ((e.value != null) && (e.oldValue == null)){ 
  //Calculate max value and add 1
  rg.offset(0, -1, 1, 1).setValue(//setvalue in colA
    rg
      .offset(2 - row, -1, sht.getLastRow() - 1, 1) //get all of colA
      .getValues()
      .reduce(function(acc, curr) {//get max of colA
        return Math.max(acc, Number(curr[0]));
      }, 0) + 1
  );
  }

  // When the value of cell with a value is removed, this becomes true.
  else if ((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue == null)) { 
  rg.offset(0, -1, 1, 1).setValue(//setvalue in colA
    rg
      .offset(2 - row, -1, sht.getLastRow() - 1, 1) //get all of colA
      .getValues()
      .reduce(function(acc, curr) {//get max of colA
        return Math.max(acc, Number(curr[0]));
      }, 0)
  ).clearContent(); // If we delete cell
  }

}
```

I tried to understand why in this case the

```
((e.value != null) && (e.oldValue == null))
```

code works when typing a value into B2,  but doesn't when pasting a value into the blank B2.

What is the underlying difference between edited/typing, and edited/pasting if that is the responsible difference?

Here's a live demo:

https://i.imgur.com/03Uoh7F.gif

**What is missing in the code for it to print in the ordinal value to A2 when copying and pasting into the blank B2?**

Here a demo with @TheMaster and @Tanaike completed:

**EDIT (new correct gif):**

https://i.imgur.com/mFKUnTL.gif

With similar result (no value in B2 when pasting into non-blank cell as well):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg = e.range,
    row = rg.rowStart,
    col = rg.columnStart,
    sht = rg.getSheet();

  //exit code
  if (col !== 2 || sht.getName() !== 'Sheet1' || row === 1) return;

  // When the empty cell is edited, this becomes true.
  if ((e.value != null) && (e.oldValue == null)){ 
  //Calculate max value and add 1
  rg.offset(0, -1, 1, 1).setValue(//setvalue in colA
    rg
      .offset(2 - row, -1, sht.getLastRow() - 1, 1) //get all of colA
      .getValues()
      .reduce(function(acc, curr) {//get max of colA
        return Math.max(acc, Number(curr[0]));
      }, 0) + 1
  );
  }

//COMPLETED PIECE

  // When the cell with a value is overwritten by a value, this becomes true.
  else if(e.oldValue!=undefined) {
  //Calculate max value and add 1
  rg.offset(0, -1, 1, 1).setValue(//setvalue in colA
    rg
      .offset(2 - row, -1, sht.getLastRow() - 1, 1) //get all of colA
      .getValues()
      .reduce(function(acc, curr) {//get max of colA
        return Math.max(acc, Number(curr[0]));
      }, 0) + 1
  );
  }

//COMPLETED PIECE


  // When the value of cell with a value is removed, this becomes true.
  else if ((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue == null)) { 
  rg.offset(0, -1, 1, 1).setValue(//setvalue in colA
    rg
      .offset(2 - row, -1, sht.getLastRow() - 1, 1) //get all of colA
      .getValues()
      .reduce(function(acc, curr) {//get max of colA
        return Math.max(acc, Number(curr[0]));
      }, 0)
  ).clearContent(); // If we delete cell
  }

}
```

**What is missing in the code for it to print in the ordinal value to A2 when copying and pasting into the non-blank B2?**

### Added (Jun 5th 2019):

In order to better understand the issue, today I tested the 16 relevent `onEdit` cases when using `e.oldValue` and `e.Value` tests with logical operators `!==`, `==`, and `&&`.

Here are the results (numbered according to Sheet2 example in the gifs here [Sheet2 (and Sheet1)](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zqFdHZ0_vp82Yn0oaLDgW3SqjAxN_qvPEKhFVBezRLs/edit?usp=sharing):

### These 10 combinations return values In Column A when pasting in Column B:

1.

```
(e.oldValue == undefined) && (e.Value == undefined)
```

https://i.imgur.com/JHD1mpS.gifv

2.

```
(e.oldValue !== undefined) && (e.Value == undefined)
```

https://i.imgur.com/zlCYJ1N.gifv

3.

```
(e.oldValue == null) && (e.Value == undefined)
```

https://i.imgur.com/Zp2uutV.gifv

4.

```
(e.oldValue !== null) && (e.Value == undefined)
```

https://i.imgur.com/XtT1MAt.gifv

9.

```
(e.oldValue == undefined) && (e.Value == null)
```

https://i.imgur.com/AEDWkHf.gifv

11.

```
(e.oldValue == null) && (e.Value == null)
```

https://i.imgur.com/5BE5vGd.gifv

12.

```
(e.oldValue !== null) && (e.Value == null)
```

https://i.imgur.com/ygqfmKe.gifv

13.

```
(e.oldValue == undefined) && (e.Value !== null)
```

https://i.imgur.com/clTkSRx.gifv

15.

```
(e.oldValue == null) && (e.Value !== null)
```

https://i.imgur.com/Whc2fcW.gifv

16.

```
(e.oldValue !== null) && (e.Value !== null)
```

https://i.imgur.com/R1xiI8M.gifv

Contrary to what one would logically expect at first glance,

It returns values in 1, 2, 3, 4, 9, 11, 12.

In accordance to logic, it returns values in 13, 15, and 16 only.

### Those 6 combinations don't return values in Column A when pasting in Column B:

5.

```
(e.oldValue == undefined) && (e.Value !== undefined)
```

https://i.imgur.com/MGL0gVk.gifv

6.

```
(e.oldValue !== undefined) && (e.Value !== undefined)
```

https://i.imgur.com/jA7dcbf.gifv

7.

```
(e.oldValue == null) && (e.Value !== undefined)
```

https://i.imgur.com/bvczvde.gifv

8.

```
(e.oldValue !== null) && (e.Value !== undefined)
```

https://i.imgur.com/Ou9zuhb.gifv

10.

```
(e.oldValue !== undefined) && (e.Value == null)
```

https://i.imgur.com/1O4jQE3.gifv

14.

```
(e.oldValue !== undefined) && (e.Value !== null)
```

https://i.imgur.com/hS6baxV.gifv

Contrary to what one would logically expect at first glance,

It returns no values in 5, 7, 8, 14.

In accordance to logic, it returns no values in 6 and 10 only.

Here all the Gifs:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7QYa.jpg

Here today's code:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rg = e.range,
    row = rg.rowStart,
    col = rg.columnStart,
    sht = rg.getSheet();

  //exit code
  if (col !== 2 || sht.getName() !== 'Sheet1' || row === 1) return;

            // When the empty cell is edited, this becomes true.
  else if (EDITS HERE) { 
  //Calculate max value and add 1
  rg.offset(0, -1, 1, 1).setValue(//setvalue in colA
    rg
      .offset(2 - row, -1, sht.getLastRow() - 1, 1) //get all of colA
      .getValues()
      .reduce(function(acc, curr) {//get max of colA
        return Math.max(acc, Number(curr[0]));
      }, 0) + 1
  )
  }


}
```

I'll see tomorrow how it behaves when combined with the added `.clearContents()` action.

### Added (Jun 8th 2019):

Thanks to the keen eye of @theMaster, I realised my previous tests (done on Jun 5th 2019 above) were indeed flawed because I use e.`V`alue instead of e.`v`alue.

Here below the corrected videos of my previous 16 tests:

1.

```
(e.oldValue == undefined) && (e.value == undefined)
```

https://youtu.be/LIW0yZIrXnw

2.

```
(e.oldValue !== undefined) && (e.value == undefined)
```

https://youtu.be/hsjrDkYhbp8

3.

```
(e.oldValue == null) && (e.value == undefined)
```

https://youtu.be/VO0ooYg9vpk

4.

```
(e.oldValue !== null) && (e.value == undefined)
```

https://youtu.be/kcIsv6IpvyM

5.

```
(e.oldValue == undefined) && (e.value !== undefined)
```

https://youtu.be/RbE1nYOBKgE

6.

```
(e.oldValue !== undefined) && (e.value !== undefined)
```

https://youtu.be/dRt3z6eO2Xo

7.

```
(e.oldValue == null) && (e.value !== undefined)
```

https://youtu.be/NKR__p6zpaU

8.

```
(e.oldValue !== null) && (e.value !== undefined)
```

https://youtu.be/2E_1mCvgx04

9.

```
(e.oldValue == undefined) && (e.value == null)
```

https://youtu.be/D8LtqDvns3U

10.

```
(e.oldValue !== undefined) && (e.value == null)
```

https://youtu.be/fy3PzZ_enKg

11.

```
(e.oldValue == null) && (e.value == null)
```

https://youtu.be/fSTEoe-M7B0

12.

```
(e.oldValue !== null) && (e.value == null)
```

https://youtu.be/QnHIdjplzfI

13.

```
(e.oldValue == undefined) && (e.value !== null)
```

https://youtu.be/brHuqvE6uWM

14.

```
(e.oldValue !== undefined) && (e.value !== null)
```

https://youtu.be/qSoDa0AuE2w

15.

```
(e.oldValue == null) && (e.value !== null)
```

https://youtu.be/W2XRG2APKFU

16.

```
(e.oldValue !== null) && (e.value !== null)
```

https://youtu.be/B2qQLOfYnCQ

The results are recorded in the previous Sheets here:

[Sheet2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zqFdHZ0_vp82Yn0oaLDgW3SqjAxN_qvPEKhFVBezRLs/edit#gid=2030662498)

I will report the logic's synthesis of the results tomorrow.

Thanks again @TheMaster for the helpful observation!

Comment: This `else if ((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue == null))`  that no edit occurred so no onEdit trigger.

Comment: Thanks @Cooper. This if is used to delete column A values when deleting adjacent values in column B. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51548690/10789707) Tanaike's demo. I updated also my second gif to the real 2nd case. Thanks.

Comment: Yes but `if (e.value==e.oldValue)` then no edit has taken place and there no onEdit trigger.

Comment: I didn't check everything, but your tests are flawed: There will be no ``Value`` in `e` ever and it'll(`e.Value`) be `undefined` always- There's only `value`(lower case). `value  is not Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your goal is that when the value of the clipboard is directly pasted to a cell, you want to execute a script by OnEdit event trigger.
- The paste action is that the value is directly pasted on the cell by copy&paste action. This is not the situation that the value is put in the cell under editing the cell.
- You want to put the Ordinal Number to the column "A" with the same row, when the following events are executed.

  - Value of the clipboard is directly pasted to a cell of the column "B".
  - Empty cell of the column "B" is manually edited.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

### Workaround:

When the value of the clipboard is pasted to a cell, both `e.value` and `e.oldValue` of `e` of the OnEdit event object become `null`. In this case, the values are the same with the situation when the value of cell with a value is removed. But there is one different cell value. It's whether the cell has a value. In this case, this can be used.

**Before you use the following sample scripts, please install the OnEdit trigger for the function of `sampleEvent()` as the installable trigger.**

### Sample 1:

This is a sample script for running `Logger.log()`, when the value of the clipboard is directly pasted to a cell.

#### Script:

```
function sampleEvent(e) {
  if ((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue == null) && (e.range.getValue() != "")) {

    // When the value of the clipboard is directly pasted to a cell, this script is run.
    Logger.log("Value of the clipboard was pasted to a cell.")

  }
}
```

- When the value of cell with a value is removed, `e.value`, `e.oldValue` and `e.range.getValue()` are `null`, `null` and `""`, respectively.
- When the value of the clipboard is directly pasted to a cell, `e.value`, `e.oldValue` and `e.range.getValue()` are `null`, `null` and `"### pasted value ###"`, respectively.

### Sample 2:

If you want to separate the script by the following situations, how about this sample script?

#### Situations:

- Empty cell was edited.
- Cell with a value was overwritten by a value.
- Value of cell with a value was removed.
- Value of the clipboard was directly pasted to a cell.

#### Script:

In this sample script, when OnEdit event trigger is fired, a dialog is opened.

```
function sampleEvent(e) {
  var prompt = "";
  var cellValue = e.range.getValue();
  if ((e.value != null) && (e.oldValue == null)) { // When the empty cell is edited, this becomes true.
    prompt = "Empty cell was edited.";

  } else if(e.oldValue != undefined) { // When the cell with a value is overwritten by a value, this becomes true.
    prompt = "Cell with a value was overwritten by a value.";

  } else if((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue == null) && (cellValue == "")) { // When the value of cell with a value is removed, this becomes true.
    prompt = "Value of cell with a value was removed.";

  } else if((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue == null) && (cellValue != "")) { // When the value of the clipboard is directly pasted to a cell, this becomes true.
    prompt = "Value of the clipboard was directly pasted to a cell.";
  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(prompt);
}
```

### Sample 3:

If you want to put the Ordinal Number to the column "A" when the value of the clipboard is directly pasted to a cell of the column "B", how about this sample script? I think that this sample script might be close to your goal.

#### Script:

```
function sampleEvent(e) {
  var prompt = "";
  var cellValue = e.range.getValue();
  if ((e.value != null) && (e.oldValue == null)) { // When the empty cell is edited, this becomes true.
    prompt = "Empty cell was edited.";
    putOrdinalNumber(e); // Put the Ordinal Number

  } else if(e.oldValue != undefined) { // When the cell with a value is overwritten by a value, this becomes true.
    prompt = "Cell with a value was overwritten by a value.";

  } else if((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue == null) && (cellValue == "")) { // When the value of cell with a value is removed, this becomes true.
    prompt = "Value of cell with a value was removed.";

  } else if((e.value == null) && (e.oldValue == null) && (cellValue != "")) { // When the value of the clipboard is directly pasted to a cell, this becomes true.
    prompt = "Value of the clipboard was directly pasted to a cell.";
    putOrdinalNumber(e); // Put the Ordinal Number

  }

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(prompt);
}

function putOrdinalNumber(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (range.getColumn() == 2 && sheet.getName() == 'Sheet1' && range.getRow() != 1 && range.offset(0, -1).getValue() == "") {
    var n = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(function(e) {return e[0] > 0}).length;
    range.offset(0, -1).setValue(n + 1);
  }
}
```

- In this sample script, only when the value of the clipboard is directly pasted to a cell of the column "B", the Ordinal Number is put to the column "A" with the same row.

  - Dialog is opened for every event.
- If you want to put the Ordinal Number by other event, please modify above script.

### Note:

- When the copied empty value is pasted to a cell, it becomes the same with the situation when the value of cell with a value is removed.
- I prepared the script for putting the Ordinal Number from your explanation. So if that was not the result you want, please modify it.

### References:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)
- [google script detect empty cell after edit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51548360)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Hello @Tanaike!

Thanks a lot for your solution! It is fantastic work and well explained. It works like a charm!
Thanks for the `prompt` way to check the script! I didn't know about that.
Thanks also for the var `n` and the `cellValue`  distinctions/separations made in the code.
Very readable and made simple for good understanding.
Beautiful code!
Understanding feels natural and intuitive. As one reads it, it pops to the eye before poping to the mind!

Comment: Love the simplicity of how you put this too:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46500020/10789707)
Understanding feels natural and intuitive. As one reads it, it pops to the eye before poping to the mind!

I've made a video of my test with your code here:
[link](https://youtu.be/mugfdCjLZZo)

Somehow, overwritten is for when we paste clipboard content over a cell with prior content in it.
Or when we type new content over a cell with prior content in it.

And removed is for when we paste blank content over a cell without prior content (blank cell).

Comment: I just added some little piece to your code to make it delete the ordinals in olumn A when we delete the adjacent cell content in Column B.

And here a video with my added code:
https://youtu.be/rhKZ7va_hnQ

With the added code here: https://pastebin.com/5NDmiGVy

Comment: `function clearOrdinalNumber(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (range.getColumn() == 2 && sheet.getName() == 'Sheet1' && range.getRow() != 1 && range.offset(0, -1).getValue() !== "") {
    var n = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().filter(function(e) {return e[0] > 0}).length;
    range.offset(0, -1).setValue(n + 1).clearContent();
  }
}`

Comment: What do you think about that delete function added script?

Now it's finally clear to me how to use `e.value` and `e.OldValue`!

I've learned a lot thanks!
Your help is much appreciated!

Be well!

Lod

Comment: @Lod Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.